# use code from excel vba addin

Tags: excel, vba

I have an xlsm file with vba code. I copied that file to a new one, removed all sheets and saved it as xlam (Excel 2010 xla macro file).

Now this file is available in File->Options->Manage Addins. But even if I select it it is not shown in the list of addins.

Now I would like to execute the code from addin from within the original xlsm file. But how?

Comment: So just to clarify 1) you've ticked the box next to your add-in, and clicked ok to install it in your add-in manager dialog box - like here http://static.joshmccarty.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/excel-connector-02.png?3cffb9. 2) the add-in still doesn't show up in the "Active Application Add-ins" section of the Excel Option Add-ins Panel - like here http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/wp-content/img200808/ExcelOptionsAddIns.png. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is open, you can use:

```
Application.Run "'add-in name here.xlam'!macro_name"
```